# How to trigger row click event of jQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatable

I'm using `jQuery Datatable` plugin for grid purposes.
When I click on a row in the grid, I want to load another page depending on the ID stored in the row.
Can you provide me with a row clickevent?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Show some code of the markup generated by the Datatable please.

Comment: Can you not just hook up a click event on `tr` elements like you would normally?

Answer (score 0):

try 
[row_callback](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
            /* Append the grade to the default row class name */
            if ( aData[4] == "A" )
            {
                $('td:eq(4)', nRow).html( '<b>A</b>' );
            }
        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [ {
                "sClass": "center",
                "aTargets": [ -1, -2 ]
        } ]
    } );
} );
```